# How to disable 'warning no department given for 'COP' message on running rubocop

Tags: rubocop

In my .rubocop.yml have some config for disabling some of the style cops.

```
Documentation:
  Enabled: false
ClassAndModuleChildren:
  Enabled: false
LineLength:
  Max: 120
GuardClause:
  Enabled: false
IfUnlessModifier: 
  Enabled: false
```

When running `rubocop` in the terminal it works fine and disables the unwanted style cops and lints as usual but every time it runs i get this warning error for all the disabled cops:

`Warning: no department given for Documentation.`

Is there a way of disabling the warning message?

Comment: What rubocop version are you using?

Comment: The version is 0.75.0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A qualified cop name is `Department/CopName`.  For example, `Style/Documentation` is qualified and `Documentation` is unqualified.

The [documentation](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/) indicates that:

> Qualifying cop name with its type, e.g., `Style`, is recommended, but not necessary as long as the cop name is unique across all types.

But they show a warning for unqualified names.  That happens [here](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/v0.75.0/lib/rubocop/cop/registry.rb#L97):

```rb
# RuboCop::Cop::Registry
def qualified_cop_name(name, path, shall_warn = true)
  badge = Badge.parse(name)
  if shall_warn && department_missing?(badge, name)
    print_warning(name, path)
  end
  return name if registered?(badge)

  potential_badges = qualify_badge(badge)

  case potential_badges.size
  when 0 then name # No namespace found. Deal with it later in caller.
  when 1 then resolve_badge(badge, potential_badges.first, path)
  else raise AmbiguousCopName.new(badge, path, potential_badges)
  end
end
```

`shall_warn` is only `false` when the `--auto-correct` option is in use.  There isn't a way to disable it currently.

The only way to silence the warning is to include the department for each cop in your config like:

```
Style/Documentation:
  Enabled: false
Style/ClassAndModuleChildren:
  Enabled: false
Metrics/LineLength:
  Max: 120
Style/GuardClause:
  Enabled: false
Style/IfUnlessModifier: 
  Enabled: false
```